# Using the ng2-pdfjs-viewer, is it possible to print all pdfs?

Tags: angular, pdf, amazon-s3, ng2-pdfjs-viewer

say i have multiple pdfs that are coming from S3 with a signed URL, is it possible in angular to create a 'print all' button and print all pdfs on the page in one go instead of pressing print on each individual pdf?

Or if it is possible to display multiple pdfs on the same component one after another so that the print button refers to all of them?

thank you any help appreciated!

Comment: Maybe look into trying to merge multiple PDF's into one, allowing you to print all of them.  I am sure there is a library to do it.

Comment: yes i considered this but feel if its possible in the ng2-pdfjs-viewer it would be a more elegant solution, i can see posts online saying it is possible but am yet to find a working example or even any docs on how to acheive it. thanks for the suggestion though!